# How to host a proxy server to bypass firewall

Tags: proxy, firewall, http-proxy, proxy-server, bypass

On my university the internet is very fast but almost everything is blocked by fortiguard, and the only allowed sites are wikipedia and facebook, I discovered that the only open ports are port 80 (HTTP) and 23 (FTP).

The internet speed on my home is 400kb/s and on my university is 1000Kb/s.
I created a web server on my home and tried with [glype](http://www.glype.com/), but glype is terrible and many javascript-based website doesn't work. Then I created a SHH server on my home (using port 23) and when I connected from my university everything works as expected, but the speed was about 50kb/s.

I really hate fortiguard because it blocks everything, even useful sites for students. I know the firewall doesnt use load balancing and the minimum speed using a proxy must be the lowest speed of both connections (host and client) minus the bandwith used by encryption.

So, **how can I create a home proxy server to bypass fortiguard??**

(I mean a real proxy server like those you can find on http://www.samair.ru/proxy/)

p.s.

- until now I created a web server and a SSH server but not a real
  proxy server.
- the dynamic ip of my home connection is not a problem
  because my router is always on.
- use a proxy is not against the rules
  of my university, I'm sure.
- the ip's that you can find on internet are in the blacklist of fortiguard, for this reason I need my own proxy server.

Comment: What kind of machine are you trying to run this on? What platform, OS, etc?

Comment: im using windows 7 o a netbook with 4gb of ram and dual core processor, but I can install linux on it if its necessary

Comment: Telnet uses port 23. FTP uses ports 20 and 21 for data and control.

Comment: You should not be trying to bypass the university's security. Were you to be discovered (and there's a good chance you will be discovered) you are going to lose internet access totally if you get thrown out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can install linux (on your home server) this should help.
[openVPN server](http://parabing.com/2011/07/10/build-your-own-openvpn-home-server-in-7-easy-steps/)

btw if the uni has blacklisted proxies, i wouldn't be surprised if they weren't too pleased with you using a proxy (should they find out)

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not you're "sure" that using a proxy isn't against the rules, consider that the system was put in place specifically to prevent users of the network visiting sites outside of a trusted list. Regardless of what you do, setting up a mechanism to subvert this is highly likely to get you into trouble and possibly banned from the network completely.

If you have a proper reason for using a site not in the permitted list, you can likely make a case to the network administrators for its inclusion in that list - such as it's a necessary site for your course research.